# QGIS Topological editing error - the new polygon overwrite the existing one after saving layer edits

Tags: qgis

I'd like to digitalizing a map and when I draw a new polygon which overlaps an existing one, at first it merges the boundaries correctly, but after i'm saving the layer edits, the new boundaries overwrite the old ones. I enabled topological editing. Anybody knows why does the QGIS do that?

I attached screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your `Avoid Intersections` option in the digitizing options is on. You can turn it off by selecting `Advanced` in the Layer selection and deselect the needed layers.

You can read up about the topological editing function in the [Editing section](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#topological-editing) of the QGIS documentation.